# Name of dot over "i" and "j"

Tags: terminology

What is the name of the dot over "i"and "j"? I know it has a name but I can't remember what that name is.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle, http://fontfeed.com/archives/a-typographic-anatomy-lesson/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather charmingly, it is called a "[tittle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle)".  The only usage of this word I can think of is in the phrase "jot or tittle", meaning "a very small amount of something."

Comment: While that's true, it's very specialist vocabulary. Most people would just call it a 'dot'.

Comment: @A.E: While that's true, it's not really necessaary to point it out *again*, since OP already used the word "dot" while asking for the *specific* name. Dave - because it's actually [the ninth letter of the Greek alphabet, transliterated as ‘**i**’](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iota), I almost made a fool of myself by suggesting ***iota***. Your reference to *"jot or tittle"* jogged my memory just in time! I briefly thought *title-tattle (**small** talk)* might be another usage, but apparently it's etymologically unrelated.

Comment: And just for fun...
http://www.english-for-students.com/Dot-1.html